# I am unable to redirect to an endpoint in flask on a remote server

Tags: flask, nginx, redirect, gunicorn

I recently built a simple flask app that uses Google API to fetch content. The app takes users query from a form and redirects the user to and endpoints that implements the API. On my local machine the app is working when i tested it with the built in flask development server. However the challenge is that the redirection does not work when I hosted the app on a remote server using Gunicorn and Nginx as a proxy. Here is a a snippet from my code:

```
From Nginx server block:

        location / {
                # First attempt to serve request as file, then
                # as directory, then fall back to displaying a 404.
                # try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
                proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:5003;
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
        }
From flask app

import secrets
from index_form import QueryForm
from api.v1.blueprints import youtube_api
from api.v1.blueprints import book_api

app = Flask(__name__)
# creating a key for CSRF
secret_key = secrets.token_urlsafe(16)
app.secret_key = secret_key
app.register_blueprint(youtube_api)
app.register_blueprint(book_api)

@app.route('/', strict_slashes=False)
def homepage():
    """A route for the homepage."""
    return render_template('index.html')

@app.route('/query', methods=['GET', 'POST'], strict_slashes=False)
def query():
    """A route to collect users query."""
    form = QueryForm()
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        data = form.search.data
        content_type = form.content.data
        if content_type == 'video':
            return redirect(url_for('youtube_api.search_videos', search_query=data))
        if content_type == 'book':
            return redirect(url_for('book_api.book_search', search_query=data))
    return render_template('project.html', form=form)
```

I just want to know why the redirection works on my local machine but not on the remote.

Comment: How does it not work? In your browser what do you put, what you expect and what do you get? Try adding a backslash to your `proxy_pass` irl configuration `proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:5003/;`

Comment: I added a backslash it did not work. my intention is for the app to redirect users to the appropriate endpoint based on the type of content they search for. for instance, if it is video content the user should be redirected to the route that handles the youtube video api. It works like that on my local machine but on the remote the page just rolls and does not redirect anywhere and does not even show a 500 server error